# How can we control mutiple process in programming?

Tags: c#

i want to ask this question especially in C# language, i dont want to ask for the code but just the way i can access this thought.
For example, when you make a simple game, just has the tank and the only actions are shoot and move, when you shoot, is mean the bullet will appear and go straight the enemy, but while the bullet is shot, i want to make a move for my tank like go up,down...how can i control two action (is mean that two action will appear at the same time, the bullet is flying while the tank is moving, not like my tank will move until the bullet reach the enemy), and so many examples can be seen in many games.
Thank you for reading and hope you answering!

Comment: multithreading is one way to do it. Advanced game development needs game-engine. Just take a look in any of these. Come back with more questions :)

Comment: you have answered your own question probably. Your game can move and shoot both actions parallely, only with the possibility of two kind of inputs. moving with arrows keys(lets say), and shooting with any other keys. So you just need to read the accepted keys and parse the actions.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly Multithreading and Asynchronous Programming Model is one way to do it.
Please take a look at the following link, which explains it further.
[Multi Threads at the same time](http://dotnetvisio.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/c-running-multiple-threads-at-same-time.html)